# Hidden blocks on Debug mode - Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I found these weird blocks in 15w51b snapshot. I used Debug mode and at the end, I found these weird blocks in this snapshot.
Can I use these in my world?
 I gonna take a picture for you guys to check it out!
[image: Weird Blocks]

Answer (score 4):

The blocks stand for the following:

```
D = Data
L = Load
C = Corner
S = Save
```

Usage:

> When obtained with the /setblock command, structure blocks do not have
> any use in game, and emit a light level of 15. However, they are used
> internally by developers to create structures. They were used to
> create the end city dungeon structures.

Minecraft Source:
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Structure_Block